# How to preserve original filename when saving images from Sanity Asset CDN?

Tags: javascript, html, sanity

Is there a way to save images from Sanity Asset CDN with their original filenames?

When using the "Save As" option, images are saved with their hashed filename, despite appending the original filename and using the `&dl=` query parameter in my URL.

> URL format:
>  `https://cdn.sanity.io/images/<projectId>/<dataset>/<hashedFileName>/<originalFilename>?<params>&dl=imageTitle`

Using this format the images still get saved with the hashed filename. How can I get "Save As" to use the original filename instead of the hashed one? Any insights or solutions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sanity offers a `storeOriginalFilename` option for image schema type. I've never used it before so I have no first-hand experience, but you should give it a try.

You can read more here:
https://www.sanity.io/docs/image-type#storeOriginalFilename-90bd9dce3f53